# Array is duplicating when adding a new item

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I have an Ionic2 app using firebase as the backend. In the Ionic app I have a product page, when I add a new product in the control panel and push it to firebase, If I am viewing the product page in the ionic app, the new product is added, but all items in the list are duplicated also.

If I were to add a new item when a user is currently viewing the product list, they will see the whole list duplicating, but if you leave that screen and visit it again, the list is back to normal with one of each item.

This is the code I am using in my ionic app to pull the products through from firebase.

```
  public menuItems: Array<any> = [];
  public selectedItems: Array<any> = [];
  menuItem: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
```

---

```
this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
      this.menuItem = af.database.list('/menuItems', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'category',
          equalTo: this.id
        }
      })

      this.menuItem.subscribe((data) => {
        this.menuItems = data;

        for (var i = 0; i <= this.menuItems.length - 1; i++) {
          if (this.menuItems[i].category == this.id) {
            this.selectedItems.push(this.menuItems[i]);
            this.items = this.selectedItems;
          }
        }
      })
```

An example:

If I have list of items like so:

- item1
- item2
- item3

When I add a new item from the dashboard, and push to firebase, the ionic app will now show the following:

- item1
- item2
- item3
- item4
- item1
- item2
- item3
- item4

I am not sure why it is doing this, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple. you have to do a little tweaking.

Change this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.menuItems.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.menuItems[i].category == this.id) {
        this.selectedItems.push(this.menuItems[i]);
        this.items = this.selectedItems;
      }
    }
```

Into:

```
        let selectedItems: any[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.menuItems.length - 1; i++) {
          if (this.menuItems[i].category == this.id) {
            selectedItems.push(this.menuItems[i]);
          }
        }
        this.items = selectedItems;
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion I tried this, but it made all products disappear and not come through at all to the product list screen?

Comment: You do `*ngFor="let item of items"` ?

Comment: Yes I am using that in my html template  <div *ngFor="let item of items.slice().reverse()"> I am using slice and reverse to reorder them.

Comment: My bad I edited it need to be `this.items = selectedItems;`
Also make sure to remove `selectedItems` from the class scope.

Comment: PERFECTO! thanks so much @Swoox you smashed it my friend! all worked perfect!